# send message from server to client via socketio

Tags: flask, socket.io

I am posting data to the server and process the data on the server. Since the page reload takes a while, I would like to send status updates to the client and display them in a div. Things like "first file being processed...", "first file done", "second file being processed"..., and so on.

My first attempt:

```
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", 'POST'])
def main():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        socketio.emit("message", {'data': 42})
        _urls = request.form['url_area'].split("\n")
        lang = request.form['lang']
        image_list = get_images(_urls, lang)
        return render_template('index.html', images=image_list)
    return render_template('index.html')

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.3.6/socket.io.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port);
    socket.on('connect', function(msg) {
        console.log("connected");
    });
    socket.on('message', function(msg) {
        console.log(msg);
    });

</script>
```

The client connects correctly. However, no message ever gets from the server to the client.

How do I need to do this?

I've looked at some examples but cannot figure out what I am doing differently. Many examples just show how to send data that the client sent, but I don't want that (right now). For now, I'd just like to send messages from the server.

**EDIT**

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

Comment: How do you handle the initialization of your socketio object in Flask?

Comment: I edited my question. I just copied the code from the official documentation.